Logging the SQL text message
In R, I am working with SQL netezza.
I set up like this:
test_con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),dsn = "test",encoding = "latin1")
dbGetQuery(test_con "select * from sometable")

I am wondering, is there some way I can save the FULL error text that is produced when the SQL does not run successfully?  R will truncate/shorten the SQL error when it becomes too long - is it possible to view the full error?

you could try tryCatch
library(DBI)

test_con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "test", encoding = "latin1")

result <- tryCatch({
  dbGetQuery(test_con, "select * from sometable")
}, error = function(e) {
  # Print full error message
  cat("Error details:\n", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
  # Save error message to a variable or file
  writeLines(conditionMessage(e), "error_log.txt")
  NULL  # Return NULL if an error occurs
})

dbDisconnect(test_con)

Or set the options to higher:
options(width = 1000)  # Set a higher width to prevent truncation

Or wrap your r script with source to capture errors.
tryCatch({
  source("your_script.R")
}, error = function(e) {
  cat("Error in sourced script:\n", conditionMessage(e), "\n")
})

Or run tools::Rcmd("BATCH --no-save yourScript.R") it will create a log file which can include the full error message.
